# Нужен ли дефис?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно пишется: 
1) Люди, вы свиньи
2) Люди, вы - свиньи

Comment: Такие лозунги Вам лучше обсудить в других местах.

Comment: Вы б на наших пляжах побывали, сразу бы с высказыванением согласились))

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, можно и так, и так.
Самый нейтральный вариант - первый, без тире (это не дефис, это тире). Однако, если Вы хотите как-то интонационно выделить слово "свиньи", подчеркнуть сказанное, сделать паузу перед этим словом, то можно поставить и тире.
То есть, все зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Нахожу первый вариант как некое обобщённое определение, второй, как констатацию факта с утверждением и неким "вызовом"-определением.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, это не дефис, а тире. а во-вторых, в целом уместны оба варианта написания, разница в экспрессии, когда во втором варианте скорее всего в конце предложения будет стоять восклицательный знак.